# How to avoid shortcuts being listed in FileDialog while filtering for specific extenstion?

Tags: java, swt, filefilter

I want to filter file based on `.blr` extension on file selector.
I am using [FileDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FFileDialog.htmlhttp://) as a file selector.

Here, I have tried to filter files for `.blr` extension. This code blocks all files with any other extensions. But Shortcuts files are getting listed along with `.blr` files.

You can check [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l6s6.png) screen shot for reference.

[image: attached]

```
FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(new Shell(), SWT.OPEN);
String[] allowedExtensions = { "*.blr" };

FileSystemView filesys = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
fileDialog.setFilterPath(filesys.getHomeDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
fileDialog.setFilterExtensions(allowedExtensions);
```

Comment: Try setting `setFilterNames` before `setFilterExtensions`, the code in `FileDialog` is doing some stuff with`filterNames`, `filterExtensions` based on their lengths which doesn't seem right.

Comment: I had tried to use `setFilterNames` but that did not work. Even description of that method says it will use description of the extension to filter the files. Same thing `setFilterExtension` does with extensions. This solution did not work.